# How to inegrate Alexa skill in Google Assistant?

Tags: alexa-skills-kit, dialogflow-es, actions-on-google

I have finished makeing a working skill in Amazon Alexa. Now, I want to try it on Google Assistant as I have found an Alexa option in the Google Assistant Integrations tab in the DialogFlow. However, whenever I upload the zip file of the Alexa skill, an unknown error occurs. What could I be doing wrong? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it straight away. Alexa and Google Assistant are separate platforms. Through Dialogflow you can only create similar intents. But you will need to add separate events, actions, etc. Also, the request and response for the platforms are different. So you will need to develop a separate app. You can reuse intents in someway and some of the business logic that is independent of the platforms.

Comment: Oh. I thought the option to upload a zip file of Alexa was that it could be used on Google Assistant. Guess I have to explore more on the development side, then. The integrations tab confused me. Thanks!  @Abhinav Tyagi